# Is there any way to prevent/detect implicit assignments from 'any' in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript I find that I sometimes have to use the 'any' type when processing parsed JSON data.  Unfortunately this makes it easy to ignore the type constraints since TypeScript allows implicit conversions from the 'any' type.

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "num": "this is a string", "str": 3 }');

var num: number = obj.num;  // num = "this is a string"!
var str: string = obj.str;  // str = 3!
```

I'm looking for a way to detect when this happens and require some sort of explicit conversion.

```
var num: number = obj.num;          // Error
var num: number = <number>obj.num;  // Ok
```

Which I could then extend with some validation functions to ensure the type is correct at runtime.

```
function toNumberChecked(val: any): number {
    if (!_.isNumber(val)) throw Error('Value is not of type "number"');
    return <number>val;
}

var num: number = toNumberChecked(obj.num);
```

Is there any way I can detect this situation to help prevent errors from getting through?  If not through the TypeScript compiler itself then maybe through some sort of separate tool?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make this happen is to change the .d.ts files you're working with by replacing `any` with `{}`. All type assertions from `{}` succeed, but it's not assignable to any type which has members.

```
function otherJSON(s: string): {} {
    // ...
    return undefined;
}

var x: number = otherJSON('3'); // Error
var y: number = <number>otherJSON('3'); // OK
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but wouldn't that mean I could no longer traverse a parsed JSON object using standard object syntax?  e.g. In my example above, if I created a new JSONParse function "(s: string) => {}" I would get an error doing 'obj.num'.

Comment: You would have to cast the result of the function to `any` to allow arbitrary traversal.

Comment: Which puts me right back at the beginning :/  I think what I'm looking for is something like the C# 'dynamic' type.  'any' gets me half way there the plain javascript types will give me errors if I try to use undefined properties, but it doesn't have the part that prevents me from performing invalid conversions.

Comment: @Screndib - what operations does C#'s `dynamic` disallow at compile time?

Comment: @DanielEarwicker I don't believe there are many cases where it causes errors at compile time, but it does do runtime checks and throws an exception for invalid conversions { dynamic x = "str"; int y = x; } which is fundamentally what I'm after.  A compile-time error/warning/whatever for implicit conversion from 'any' would just be a way for me ensure I'm doing those checks manually.  I suppose a version of any that automatically added those runtime checks would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript throws errors at compile time. At compile time though there it has no information about the properties of the parsed JSON. This is why you're currently not getting any errors.

You have two options:

1. If you know for sure what types the properties will have you can write an interface. (I've altered the matching of number and string so it is more readable.)

   ```
   interface JSONResult{
       num:number;
       str:string;
   }
   var result:JSONResult = JSON.parse('{ "str": "this is a string", "num": 3 }');
   var x:number = result.num;
   var y:number = result.str; // error
   ```
2. If you do not control the JSON you need to do runtime validation. This would be the case for example if you receive the JSON via http.

Comment: Correct, what I'm after is a way to write safer code by warning me when I fail to do the runtime validation.

Comment: I think I'd write a wrapper class around the json parser that has functions like `getNumber( propertyName:string):number`. In that function I'd do the validation. The only thing you'd then have to make sure is that you're not using JSON.parse anymore.